# Preciso contar uma quantidade de números específico por coluna em uma matriz

Tags: python, matriz

Estou fazendo um programa que lê a quantidade de número "1" por linha na matriz e preciso achar a quantidade de números "1" por coluna. Acontece que não estou conseguindo montar um código que leia apenas as colunas e some os números 1. Preciso que em `dx` saia a quantidades de 1 em cada linha, e em `dy` a quantidade de 1 em cada coluna.

Segue abaixo minha tentativa:

```
import random

n = 10
mat = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
dx = []
dy = []
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        valor = mat[j][i]
        print("\t", valor, end='')
    print("\n")

for i in range(n):
    #conta linha
    dx.append(mat[i].count(1))

for j in range(10):
    dy.append(mat[j].count(1))

print(dx,dy, sep = '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Presumindo que esse código só será usado em matrizes quadradas
mat = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

ordem = len(mat)

coluna = lambda c: [linha[c] for linha in mat]
contaLinha = lambda l: len([*filter(lambda e: e == 1, mat[l])])
contaColuna = lambda c: len([*filter(lambda e: e == 1, coluna(c))])

dx = [contaLinha(l) for l in range(ordem)] 
dy = [contaColuna(c) for c in range(ordem)] 

print(dx, dy, sep = '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza existe uma forma mais *pythonica* de fazer isso mas esta foi a minha solução:

```
mat = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

dx = []
dy = []

#soma as quantidades por linha
for linha in range(len(mat)):
  soma = 0
  for i in range(len(mat[0])):
    if mat[linha][i] == 1:
      soma += 1
  dx.append(soma)

  #soma as quantidades por coluna
for coluna in range(len(mat[0])):
  soma = 0
  for i in range(len(mat)):
    if mat[i][coluna] == 1:
      soma += 1
  dy.append(soma)

print(dx)
print(dy)
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: Se respondi sua pergunta, não se esqueça de clicar no tick verde no lado esquerdo para ajudar outras pessoas no site que tenham a mesma dúvida que você